# What does " " mean in java?

Tags: java

I must do an exercise from the book. The exercise is:

Write a filter that reads in a sequence of integers and prints the integers, removing repeated values that appear consecutively. For example , if the input is 1 2 2 1 5 1 1 7 7 7 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 , your program should print 1 2 1 5 1 7 1.

```
public class B1_5_6
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int waarde1 = StdIn.readInt(); //eerste waarde die je invult
    String reeks = waarde1 + " "; //die mag dus altijd geprint worden

    while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
    {
      int waarde2 = StdIn.readInt(); //volgende waardes die je invult
      if (!(waarde1 == waarde2)) // als die niet hetzelfe is dan de voorgaande waarde, mag je dat getal ook uitprinten
      {
        waarde1 = waarde2;
        reeks = reeks + waarde2 + " "; // reeks is de waardes die al uitgeprint mogen worden en daar komt de nieuwe ingevulde waarde bij
      }
    }
    StdOut.println(reeks);
  }
}
```

My question is:

I do not understand the second line:
String reeks = waarde1 + " "; //die mag dus altijd geprint worden

What does this " " mean?
It means you can fill whatever you want in right? Or does it mean empty??

Maybe a simple thing to understand for people, but I do not understand this hole line and why you make it.
I get it that you need the numbers in sequence after each other without getting a number equal to the number in front of it.. like 2 2 makes 2. but I do not understand what this basic

" " mean.
i made alot of exercises alrdy but I still do not get what this means, and I can not find it anywhere.

Thanks for the detailed description and explanations.

Comment: javascript and java are two different language.

Comment: ```" "``` is a space (een spatie in het Nederlands). The double quotes delimite the start and the end of the string, so the value is what's between the quotes. And it is a space.

Comment: You're building up a string in the format: `number + space + number + space + number`. " " is a String of 1 space

Answer (score 1):

It’s used as a separator in a string. Basically numbers separated by a space

Comment: And if you don't use ```" "```, the output would be 1215171 instead of 1 2 1 5 1 7 1

Answer (score 0):

The String 'reeks' creates a string with the value and adds a space after it. The string " " is what includes the space. It's just a separator to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have three strings contains numbers.

```
String a = "123", b = "456", c= "789";
```

If you want to merge this strings you need to use + operator.

```
String d = a + b; // 123456
String e = a + c  // 123789
```

Sometimes you need to add a separator between those. So let's say we want to add an empty space

```
String f = a + " " + b // 123 456
String g = a + " " + c // 123 789
```

It's easy to add such that separators but when you use loops such as for and while It's harder to understand.
Let's say you have an array contains numbers as strings.

```
String[] arr = {"12", "34", "56", "78","9"};
```

and you want to merge them using for

```
String merged = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    merged = merged + arr[i];
}
System.out.println(merged) // 123456789
```

but if you want a empty space between each merge. You need to add empty space after merging the next element. You can see the pattern below.

```
merged = merged + arr[i] + " ";

//In iteration 1
merged = "" + "12" + " "; // "12 "

//In iteration 2
merged = "12 " + "34" + " "; // "12 34 ";

//In iteration 3
merged = "12 34 " + "56"+ " "; // "12 34 56 ";
```